# AttributeError: 'ModbusIOException' object has no attribute 'bits'

Tags: python, python-3.x, modbus, pymodbus

```
from pymodbus.client import ModbusTcpClient

PLC_IP = '192.168.0.200'
PLC_PORT = 502
client = ModbusTcpClient(PLC_IP, PLC_PORT)
status = client.connect()
print(status)
result = client.read_coils(1,5)
if result.bits[0] == True:
    print("Hello world")
client.close()
```

It shows the error I put in the title.
I recently changed my pc and I think it might be my pymodbus version.
Thanks and I wish to have luck finding a solution to my problem.

Comment: Hello Lee, to be able to answer your question we need as a minimum: the complete output of the error and some information on your server (it seems to be a PLC, but you should at least add brand and model and some high-level description of the code it is running). Are you sure the code is properly defining a Modbus server with coils located at the addresses you are reading? Are you able to reproduce this issue if you use an off-the-shelf client like [QModMaster](https://sourceforge.net/projects/qmodmaster/#:~:text=QModMaster%20is%20a%20free%20Qt,all%20traffic%20on%20the%20bus.)?

Comment: In addition to the above It would be worth checking for an error (i.e. [`if result.isError()`](https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus/blob/dev/examples/client_calls.py#L93)) before attempting to make use of the result (the error text will provide more info as to the issue).